# How can I access my GoDaddy account if the email and pin was changed by a hacker?

Tags: domains, godaddy, accounts

My GoDaddy account was stolen and the hacker had its combined email and pin code changed. I submitted the regain access form via `changeupdate.com`. In addition, I emailed `change@secureserver.net` to explain myself clearly with sufficient documents.

However, the change team asked me to cancel the [protected registration](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-protected-registration-1286). I didn't do as they requested for the simple reason that once I cancel the protected registration, the hacker might transfer my domains away. Therefore, I replied back to ask the reason and restated that I just want to retrieve my GoDaddy account, instead of cancelling the protected registration. **Since then on, I have't received any more responses from them.**

I also contacted their customer office via online chat and phone, but there's nothing they can do for me due since I don't have the PIN code (it was modified by the hacker).

**What should I do to retrieve my GoDaddy account?**

Comment: There is something they can do- they just don't want to use their imagination and break procedure. Hire a lawyer. You paid money for a service that you are no longer receiving satisfactory support/response/performance for. The attorney can write a letter to their legal department and attorney to attorney, they can get this done for you and it should not cost you a dime in the end. Otherwise, one of my tricks is to call the CEO and ask for his/her help. That has always worked for me and few of them have become my friends. How can that be bad??

Comment: GoDaddy, like most credible registrars, is very careful not to allow fraudulent access to domain accounts. Their first level support team will want to compare the registrant information against your government issued ID and business documentation. If you have private registration on the domain, they'll have to contact their [Domains by Proxy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/domains-by-proxy-faq-421) department for confirmation. I do not think you can cancel that by the way unless you have access to your account, so that requirement is a bit odd sounding...

Comment: I would _call_ their domain support department (in the U.S. if you can) and ask them to escalate it to a higher team. They should be able to confirm the pin and email change, and what IP address was used, along with other critical information to detect if that was done fraudulently. Something else that's odd is that you should have been sent an email to _your_ email address on the account that it was being changed. I'd look for that and provide that to them as well, along with providing information like the credit card used to register the domain with.

Comment: Keep in mind that they're constantly under a barrage of attempts by unscrupulous parties trying to subvert domain names, so it may take some time for them to respond...and some persistence on your end. On the flip side, that demonstrates that it's not easy to pull off domain hijacking these days. In any case, even if it's transferred, they can get the domain back since that would violate ICANN's provisions, so don't fret - if you're the registrant and account holder, you wont' lose the domain.

Comment: ＠dan, Is the phone number of their domain support department `(480) 505-8877`?  I am in France.

Comment: @dan Thank you for refining the question. Their change team might mistakenly assume that I would like to transfer away my domain names to another GoDaddy account.

Comment: No problem Yes, that's the correct number for the U.S. Here are their [international numbers](https://www.godaddy.com/contact-us.aspx) including France, however they might be to call centers with less experienced/restricted agents, so if you can call internationally (like through Skype), I'd recommend that. Be sure to let them know you're requesting to have the incident "escalated" to second-level support. They're trained to protect accounts if you're missing the PIN, but you should be able to confirm the credit card and phone number used for the account to purchase the domain with.

Comment: They have all the purchase order history, as well as account update history for your account, so they should be able to authenticate you using that information. If you're still having trouble, comment back with an "incident" number and domain (I'll delete it after read), and try to help - I have a close working relationship with them.

Comment: @dan thx for your constant help. I will follow your advice.

Comment: @dan sorry for my careless. The change team asks me to cancel the protected registration, instead of the whois privacy. Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contact GoDaddy directly.  Even though SecureServer is connected (and maybe even be them) you need to go directly to GoDaddy.  Their phone number is on their website at the top as is a link that you can use to contact their chat support.

They should be able to see the account changes along with which IPs made those changes.  From there, they can help you get the account back, ideally.